# Inheritance in Java. 2 children that can't access each other's overriden methods

Tags: java

Suppose I have `class/interface A` that is `extended/implemented` by `class B` and `class C`. `Class/interface A` contains `method X`. Is there a way to have `method X` without a body (`X();`) and so it must be implemented by `class B` and `class C`, but not give `class B` and `class C` (or any other class except possibly `class/interface A`) access to each other's `method X`?

```
? class/interface A {
  ? X();
}

? class B extends/implements class/interface A {
  @Override
  ? X() {
    ...code...
  }
}

? class C extends/implements class/interface A {
  @Override
  ? X() {
    ...code...
  }
}
```

I am not sure of modifiers, represented with question marks above, and I am not sure if A should be a class or interface.

**EDIT:**
Additionally, instances of classes B and C are created in `class D`. The instance of `class C` in `class D` is constructed with the instance of `class B` in `class D` as a parameter, which is set as a class variable which this instance of `class C` is constantly getting data from. I do not want this instance of `class C` to be able to call its class variable object `B`'s `method X`.

Comment: If I understand you correct, you want to give your method `X()` the visibility `protected`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `C` has access to all `protected` and `public` methods of `B`. So the only option is to make the method `private`. But you can not enforce a private method with `abstract` or an `interface`.

Comment: Who exactly should be able to call X? (Only A?). And why is exact access so important? (But the closes thing to what you want, is that a,b and c should be classes, and ? should be protected.

Comment: I have to wonder if this is possibly an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) in disguise. Consider telling more background of the overall problem that you're trying to solve with this program, the motivation behind your question. Also please show real code rather than kind-of sort-of code.

Comment: X would need to be implemented differently in b and c, and they are just helper methods that are called in a few places in b and c (b calls b's X in a few places, and c calls c's X in a few places). It would just be confusing to be able to call b's X from c and the reciprocal.

Comment: OOP problems...why don't you just NOT call b's X from c and vice versa. This is when you know you're in deep

Comment: @MathiasStrohkirch But if the method is only called directly on b and c, why do you want the method to be defined in A at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided classes B and C do not live in the same package as class A, you can make `X` protected abstract in A.

This implies that you will need to make A an abstract *class* not an interface because interface methods are always public.

So you will have A:

```
package a.b.c

public abstract class A {
    protected abstract Foo X();
}
```

Create B in a new package

```
package a.b.d

public class B extends a.b.c.A {
    // ... implement X
}
```

Create C in a different package

```
package a.b.e

public class C extends a.b.c.A {
    // ... implement X
}
```

Now if you want class D to be able to call `X`, you will need to place D in the same package as A i.e. `a.b.c`, but you will need to cast each of them to `A` in order to call `X`.

```
package a.b.c

public class D {
    public D(a.b.d.B b, a.b.e.C c) {
        // ... call ((A)b).X() or ((A)c).X()
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Essentially creating "private" methods in B and C by making the methods protected and putting them in their own package. Thank you